# Fetching the input value from textarea in a loop from an array of objects using reactjs. How to do so?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I managed to display X amount of text areas based on the JSON object data I received. I'm wondering how would i obtain **A SINGLE** user input when they input something in the textarea. I manage to input and get the textarea value but all the textarea values seem to change to the value I enter. How would I enter and obtain **ONE SINGLE** value and only display what the user inputs for that index only?

**DISPLAYING THE TEXTAREAS BASED ON THE DATABASE VALUES, however the input values are not editable or savable by my button**

```
const WorkInProgressHLEDevDays = () =>{
  return (
    <tr>
    <th> TEXTAREAs </th>
    {this.state.WIPHLEsData.map((HLEDevDayTextAreas, i) => (
        <td key={i}>
        <textarea className="HLEDevDays" onChange={this.handleChange} value={HLEDevDayTextAreas.HLEDevDays} spellcheck="false">

        </textarea>
        </td>
    ))}

    </tr>

  )
}
```

[LINK TO HOW IT LOOKS WHEN USER TYPES SOMETHING IN THE TEXTAREA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTkMk.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having is that, for every one of the `<textarea>` JSX elements you return from your `map()` method, they're all reading the **same** value off of state beacause they all use the same key.

Here's the snippet where that's happening.

`value ={this.state.jiraWIPHLEsHLEDevDays}`

Hence, as you type in *any* of the text areas, they all render the same text because that's how they're set up. Since you're generating the text areas from a `map()` method, the text areas themselves will be unique with keys, but you're supplying each of them all with the same key for their input `value` in state.

What you'll need to do is *dynamically* create and update the value for each textarea. [React has a method for doing this](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs) by supplying each input with a `name` attribute. This will allow you to target that unique value (`e.target.name`) in your `handleChange` method.

But, again, since you're creating the text areas dynamically, you'll also have to dynamically create a unique `value` attribute for each. You can do this pretty easily just by using string interpolation to create a unique `value` attribute as you return the text areas from the `map()` method.

As I've done below, ensure that the values of the `name` and `value` attributes match, because `handleChange()` will set the `name` attribute to component state as you type, and in turn your text area will expect to be able read a value of the **same key** off of state.

Check out and run the snippet I've supplied below for the details of everything, and to test the implementation.

```js
class RenderTextAreas extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      issues: {
        iOne: 'an issue',
        iTwo: 'another issue',
        iThree: 'yet another issue'
      }
    };
  }
  handleChange = e => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    // create a variable called "name" and store the name attribute in it
    // this variable's value will be unique for each text area
    let name = e.target.name;
    // set that to state, along with the input value
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(this.state.issues).map((issue, i) => (
          <textarea
            key={i}
            placeholder={`${issue}_value`}
            // supply a unique "name" attribute using string interpolation 
            name={`${issue}_value`}
            // read each unique value by using a combination of
            // bracket notation and string interpolation that matches
            // the name attribute above
            value={this.state[`${issue}_value`]}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<RenderTextAreas />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

I hope that this helps solve your problem! Let us know.

Comment: Thank you I will check this tomorrow!

Comment: @bobb1213131 My pleasure! This is an interesting issue because it sheds light on React's dynamic nature, and the issue itself might not always be immediately apparent. But it was definitely a fun one to go through.

Comment: Hello, it seems to be working, but I have an issue, when getting textarea values, I am trying to insert the values in my database, then whenever i refresh my page, the textarea values will display the values stored in the database. It seems to only insert the last inserted value from the list of textareas.

Comment: To be more specific, let's say i click Save the **HLE DAYS button**, it will update the **HLEDevDays value** in the database based on which **textarea key is being updated**, then when inserted in database, when I refresh my page, the data will be displayed (although this i can easily do by a for loop and fetching the data from the api)

Comment: I see. Well, given your original question, the solution I've provided above is a solve for ensuring input values are unique for each text area generated *while the user is typing*. If you need to update the DB with the user input on click, and then display that on page refresh, you could initially render the value stored in the DB, and then on click of that element, render a text area to edit that value. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes let me show you what I have so far. The textareas value is set to the values stored from database, but the values are **not editable** because I am just assigning the value to the values I fetch from database, I will edit my code section, I've been stuck whole day yesterday XD